# "OR" operator in RegEx syntax

Tags: php, regex

OK, I've worked with RegEx *numerous* times but this is one of the things I honestly can't get my head around. And it looks as if I'm missing something rather simple...

So, let's say we want to match "AB" or "AC". In other words, "A" followed by either "B" OR "C".
This would be expressed like `A[BC]` <del>or `A[B|C]`</del> or `A(B|C)` and so on.

Now, what if A,B,C are not just single letters but sub-expressions?

---

Please, have a look at this example here (well, I admit it doesn't look that... simple! lol) : http://regexr.com?382a4

I'm trying to match `capital =` (and its variations) followed by either :

- Pattern 1
- Pattern 2

Why is it that using the `|` operator only works on the latter part (my regex also matches "Pattern 2" withOUT preceding `capital =`). Please note that I've also tried using positive look-arounds, but without any success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original regex could be summarized as:

```
capital = (ABC)|(DEF)
```

This matches `capital = ABC` *or* `DEF`. Add an extra pair of `()` that wraps the `|` clause properly.

[Demo here](http://regexr.com?382aa)

Comment: Holy crap. And I thought I had already done that! lol Yep, it works. Just like that.

Comment: Fortunately regexr did a good job highlighting the groups. I was lost otherwise.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's one of those cases where the solution is so obvious that I actually forgot trying it... Anyway... Thanks a lot. (Waiting a few more minutes, before finally accepting it as the correct answer). Have a nice day! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually `[B|C]`  is incorrect, `(B|C)` is correct.

### Character classes

In RegEx jargon `[]` is called a *character class* and it is used to represent one (single) character according to the options listed between the brackets.

In your case `[B|C]` matches either `B` or `|` or `C`. We can correct this by using `[BC]` to match either `B` or `C`. This matches exactly one character either `B` or `C`.

### Capturing groups

In RegEx jargon `()` is called a *capturing group*. It is used to create boundaries between adjacent groups and whatever it matches will be present in the output array of a preg_match or as a variable in preg_replace.

Within that group you can us the `|` operator to specify that you want to match either whatever's before or whatever's after the operator.

This can be used to match strings with more than one characters such as `(Ana|Maria)` or various structures such as `([a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+)`.

You can also use the `|` outside of a capturing group such as `(group-1)|(group-2)` and you can also use subgrouping such as `((group-1)|(group-2))`.

Comment: What about that : http://regexr.com?382a7 - and it's still not an answer to the original question...

Comment: Well, ok, I now get your point. Rather illuminating I must admit. What about the core question?

Comment: [B|C] would mean `"B" or "|" or "C"` for a length of one character

Comment: I like to provide insight rather than direct solutions, in the hopes that knowing the names of certain concepts you will more easily search for solutions. Proper use of jargon in google searches works wonders in our field of work.

Comment: If I have time I also work on the direct answer usually sometime after I offered the initial insight -- this gives OP time to workout the problem on his own and perhaps learn more by doing so (it's also much more satisfactory for him to know he beat the problem rather than some guy on the internet).

Comment: I faced the same issue in Laravel 8 and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this regexp:

```
capital = (ABC|XYZ)
```

should work (if I did correctly understand your request...)